# asp.net mvc is not using the controller factory specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC Preview 2 that is installed with VS2010 Beta 2. I am hooking up WindsorControllerFactory like so:

```
Container = new WindsorContainer();
Container.RegisterControllers(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(Container));
```

My HomeController has one dependency that is passed into the constructor, when running I am getting the following error:

**No parameterless constructor defined for this object.**

> ```
> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for
> ```
>
> this object.]
>          System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean&
>   bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>          System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
>          System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean
>   fillCache) +230
>          System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
>          System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type) +6
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   +522
>
> ```
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
> ```
>
> controller of type
>   'Xenotar.WedPlannerPro.Controllers.HomeController'.
>   Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.]
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   +659
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)
>   +198
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) +86
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) +36
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +181
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +75

By looking at this stack trace it does not look like MVC is using the WindsorControllerFactory but instead it still uses the DefaultControllerFactory?

When doing this in MVC 1.0 it works.

**SOLUTION**

The MvcContrib is not compatible with ASP.NET MVC 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to modify MvcContrib to work with ASP.NET MVC 2.  The code for controller registration is pretty minimal.